# How to read the Model of the XSD Elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I am entirely new to XML Schema and am trying to read the Syntax of the different Model wich we have for the xsd elements.

This for example is the Model of the CompleyType ( Syntax)

```
<complexType
  abstract = Boolean : false 
  block = (#all | List of (extension | restriction))
  final = (#all | List of (extension | restriction))
  id = ID 
  mixed = Boolean : false
  name = NCName 
  {any attributes with non-schema Namespace...}>
Content: (annotation?, (simpleContent | complexContent | ((group | all | 
choice | sequence)?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?))))
</complexType>
```

But is quiet diffcult for me to read, so i will break it down and
start with several syntax and the possibilites
for it, it would great if someone would check it.

```
The Syntax (a1?,a2?)
```

Does this mean i have this posibilities? ( not proved)

```
(a1,a2)
(a1)
(a2)
(empty)
```

The Syntax

```
(a1|a2)?
```

Does this mean i have this posibilities? ( i proved)

```
(a1)
(a2)
(empty)
```

The Syntax

```
(a1*,a2*)
```

Does this mean i have this posibilities? ( not proved)

```
(a1,a1,a2,a2)
(a2,a2)
(a1,a1)
(a1)
(a2)
(empty)
```

The Syntax

```
(a1|a2)*
```

Does this mean i have this posibilities? (proved)
could it be thaht (a1*,a2*) above has the same posbilities?

```
(a1,a1,a2,a2)
(a2,a2)
(a1,a1)
(a1)
(a2)
(empty)
```

The Syntax

```
(a1|a2)
```

Does this mean i have this posibilities? (proved)

```
(a1)
(a2)
```

The Syntax

```
(a1,a2)
```

Does this mean i have this posibilities? (not proved)

```
(a1,a2)
```

Comment: It's quite amusing really that the XSD specification uses a non-XSD syntax for describing content models within the schema itself (although the normative form is the schema-for-schema-documents contained in an appendix.) But this shorthand syntax is basically borrowed from DTDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `(a1?,a2?)` means an optional a1 followed by an optional a2 and would allow all of the examples you listed:

```
(a1,a2)
(a1)
(a2)
(empty)
```

Yes, `(a1|a2)?` means optionally a1 or a2 and would allow all of the options you listed:

```
(a1)
(a2)
(empty)
```

but **not** (a1, a2)

Yes, `(a1*,a2*)` means zero or more a1's followed by zero or more a2's and would allow all of the options you listed:

```
(a1,a1,a2,a2)
(a2,a2)
(a1,a1)
(a1)
(a2)
(empty)
```

Yes, `(a1|a2)*` means zero or more a1's or a2's in any order.  So, yes, the options you listed are all allowed:

```
(a1,a1,a2,a2)
(a2,a2)
(a1,a1)
(a1)
(a2)
(empty)
```

As well as `(a2, a1)`, which would **not** be allowed by `(a1*, a2*)`

Yes, `(a1|a2)` means either a1 or a2 and would allow all of the options you listed:

```
(a1)
(a2)
```

Yes, `(a1,a2)` means a1 followed by a2 and would allow the possibility you listed:

```
(a1,a2)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks. You wrote (a1*, a2*) the combination (a2,a1)

Comment: First of all, thanks. You wrote bye the syntax (a1*, a2*) the combination (a2,a1) would not be allowed, but i ask me why? it should be possible? * = means zero or unbounded. I am wrong in this point?

Comment: Yes, * means zero or more but (a1*, a2*) allows zero or more a1 first **then** zero or more a2.